# My GcmTaskService provokes ANR

Tags: android, google-play-services, realm, android-anr-dialog

I made a Service that aims at retrieving data on a server every 10 hours when internet is on.

I've very rarely used Service before and I don't understand what happen there,but when I start my app, I get an ANR before the first layout is displayed, after a moment the layout appears and I can continue (but I've noticed one other screen change that is now very slow) :

```
E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.m360.android.debug
                                                  PID: 17742
                                                  Reason: executing service com.m360.android.debug/com.m360.android.service.offline.SyncOfflineContentService
                                                  Load: 11.95 / 12.06 / 12.2
                                                  CPU usage from 0ms to 7113ms later:
                                                    95% 17742/com.m360.android.debug: 93% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 4145 minor 1 major
                                                    46% 2133/system_server: 19% user + 26% kernel / faults: 5070 minor 4 major
                                                    0% 335/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9088 minor 5 major
                                                    13% 4932/com.android.phone: 4.7% user + 8.2% kernel / faults: 3168 minor
                                                    8.1% 4109/com.android.systemui: 3.6% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 2137 minor
                                                    6.3% 21043/com.google.android.apps.maps: 3% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 709 minor
                                                    5% 25184/adbd: 0.5% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 2042 minor
                                                    2.6% 264/surfaceflinger: 0.7% user + 1.9% kernel
                                                    2.6% 4922/com.quicinc.cne.CNEService: 1.2% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 810 minor
                                                    0% 4927/com.qualcomm.qti.tetherservice: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 806 minor 2 major
                                                    1.1% 188/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
                                                    1.1% 193/ueventd: 0.4% user + 0.7% kernel
                                                    0.8% 6737/mpdecision: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
                                                    0.5% 16314/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                    0.4% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                    0.4% 3487/com.android.chrome: 0.4% user + 0% kernel / faults: 350 minor 60 major
                                                    0.4% 16316/kworker/3:1: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                    0.4% 30162/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                    0.2% 7/kworker/u:0H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 159/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 1047/kworker/u:5: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 1457/com.whatsapp: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.2% 6653/irq/33-cpubw_hw: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 13154/kworker/0:0H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 16313/kworker/3:0H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.2% 30595/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                    0.1% 181/boost_sync/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.1% 184/boost_sync/3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.1% 212/logd: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.1% 261/healthd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.1% 334/netd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 18 minor
                                                    0% 371/oemlogkit: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.1% 10135/com.google.android.talk: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.1% 16176/logcat: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.1% 22082/com.google.android.apps.messaging: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
                                                    0.1% 25409/kworker/u:3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                   +0% 18943/migration/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18944/kworker/2:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18945/kworker/2:0H: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18946/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18947/kworker/2:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18955/migration/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18956/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18957/kworker/1:0H: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18958/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                  70% TOTAL: 44% user + 24% kernel + 0.7% iowait + 0.1% softirq
                                                  CPU usage from 6332ms to 6867ms later:
                                                    92% 17742/com.m360.android.debug: 92% user + 0% kernel
                                                      90% 17742/0.android.debug: 90% user + 0% kernel
                                                    5.6% 2133/system_server: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 9 minor
                                                      5.6% 2241/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel
                                                      1.8% 4039/Binder_3: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
                                                    4.6% 21043/com.google.android.apps.maps: 0% user + 4.6% kernel / faults: 19 minor
                                                      4.6% 21043/droid.apps.maps: 0% user + 4.6% kernel
                                                    5% 25184/adbd: 0% user + 5% kernel / faults: 166 minor
                                                      3.3% 25184/adbd: 0% user + 3.3% kernel
                                                     +0% 18939/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    2.4% 264/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 2.4% kernel
                                                      1.2% 298/DispSync: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
                                                      1.2% 324/EventThread: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
                                                    1.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
                                                    1.1% 7/kworker/u:0H: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
                                                    1.3% 6737/mpdecision: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
                                                      1.3% 6756/mpdecision: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
                                                    1.4% 16314/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
                                                   +0% 18938/sh: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                   +0% 18942/ps: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                  54% TOTAL: 40% user + 14% kernel
03-20 18:20:02.174 2133-18959/? E/ActivityManager: Error reading /data/anr/traces.txt
                                                   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/anr/traces.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                       at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:236)
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$21.run(ActivityManagerService.java:13183)
                                                    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                       at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                       at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:236) 
                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$21.run(ActivityManagerService.java:13183)
```

Note also that `onRunTask` is never called (well the log at first line is never displayed)

Gcm version : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'`
maybe that's the issue I've updated it this morning, before I started to get the ANRs

the way I defined it in my manifest :

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.offline.SyncOfflineContentService"
        android:description="@string/connection"
        android:exported="true"

        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

my service :

```
public class SyncOfflineContentService extends GcmTaskService {

 private final static String TAG = "SyncOfflineContentSer";

 //private final static long SYNC_PERIOD_SECONDS = 36000;
 private final static long SYNC_PERIOD_SECONDS = 30;
 private final static String PERIODIC_SYNC_TAG = "SyncOfflineContentService Done";

 private final Api api;
 private final ImageManagerFactory imageManagerFactory;
 private final FileManager fileManager;

 public SyncOfflineContentService() {
  api = Api.getInstance();
  imageManagerFactory = new ImageManagerFactory();
  fileManager = new FileManager(api.getOkHttpClient());
 }

 @Override
 public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
   Log.i(TAG, "onRunTask called");

   try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    try {

     //some networking

     realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Realm realm) {
       //storing data in Realm storage
      }
     });
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  } //auto close

 return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
}

public static void scheduleSync(final Context ctx) {
 Log.i(TAG, "scheduleSync");

 GcmNetworkManager gcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(ctx);
 PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
  .setPeriod(SYNC_PERIOD_SECONDS) // occurs at *most* once this many seconds - note that you can't control when
  .setRequiredNetwork(PeriodicTask.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED) // various connectivity scenarios are available
  .setTag(PERIODIC_SYNC_TAG) // returned at execution time to your endpoint
  .setService(SyncOfflineContentService.class) // the GcmTaskServer you created earlier
  .setPersisted(true) // persists across reboots or not
  .setUpdateCurrent(true) // replace an existing task with a matching tag - defaults to false!
  .build();
 gcmNetworkManager.schedule(periodicTask);


}

public static void stopSync(Context ctx) {
 Log.i(TAG, "stopSync");
 GcmNetworkManager gcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(ctx);
 gcmNetworkManager.cancelAllTasks(SyncOfflineContentService.class);
}
}
```

I was inspired by this blog post : 
http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2016/04/26/implementing-gcm-network-manager-for-periodic-network-requests-on-android/

thanks a lot !

Comment: It means you're executing a transaction on the UI thread, but there is already an ongoing transaction in the service.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what do you mean "transaction" ? Realm transactions ? Also why is the service running before I even call scheduleSync ? Thanks !

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm sorry but I don't understand, how could there be a transaction whereas this sevice is not supposed to be running.

Comment: It seem to happen only at first launch

Comment: Migration maybe?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Realm Migration ? I'm sorry this is too enigmatic for me

Comment: also before the ARN, this is logged : `ActivityManager: Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{dd15e33 u0 [...]SyncOfflineContentService}`

Comment: Are you using a crash reporting service such as Firebase Crash Reporting?